# Including a clause in an Eloquent query only if variable exists

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a page that pulls GET request data.

So I have: `example.com/page?filter1=1&filter2=false`

Depending on the request, sometimes there may be a `filter3` or `filter4` or any combination of a number of 'filters'.

In my controller doing an `Input::all();` and then wish to query my model/database.

For example: `User::where('filter1', '=' , Input::get('filter1'));`

That's just an example. How do I add to that query dynamically depending on which filters exist in the GET request?

These filters will be filtering data, and I want all the returned rows to include all of these filters.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use an array `example.com/page?filter[1]=1&filter[2]=false&filter[abc]=nothing` Then you have a `filter` array in POST over which you can iterate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the filters are named exactly like the db fields, you can just pass them as array to `where()`.

I recommend using `except()` so you have control over the filtered attributes.

```
$filters = Input::except('filter1', 'filter2', 'filter3');
$users = User::where($filters)->get();
```

---

If the filter names don't always match or you need a different operator than `=` you can add where's conditionally like this:

```
$query = User::where('foo', 'bar');
if(Input::has('one')){
    $query->where('filter1', '>', Input::get('one'));
}
$users = $query->get();
```

And if you have no unconditional where and need something "to start with" you can just use `query()` for that:

```
$query = User::query();
// add wheres...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically add all the where()-s to your query and after done building the query just use the get() to get corresponsing collections.

```
$query=User::where(where("filter1", Input::get("filter1"));
if(Input::has("filter2")) {
  $query=$query->where("filter2", Input::get("filter2"));
}
$users=$query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue, I created a package to manage it automatically with minor pains.

Give it a try!

https://github.com/ferpetrelli/scoped-controller

It's a simplified version of the gem has_scope from RoR.